# Adding additional directed arcs in a graph (tikz picture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I need

1. have all rectangles representing the nodes to be of the same size or at least the same size at each level.
2. have additional directed arcs: in particular, I need a directed arc from (1,3) to (1,4), from (1,4) to (8,5), from (8,5) to (4,6), and from (4,6) to (0,7). That is, with the current structure I get only one predecessor but I need multiple potential predecessors. Is that possible by modifying my code? If not, what's a better structure?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\begin{document}
    
\def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\shft{-6*\lvld} % Calculate the yshift for the green tree
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
                        level 4/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=black,thick,-latex}}%,
                        %edgeup/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=green!50!black,thick,latex-}}
                        ]
        \node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (A) {(1,58)}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B1) {(7,59)}
                child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (C1) {(3,40)}
                    child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (D1) {(9,1)}
                        child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (E1) {(65,1)}
                            child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (F1) {(1,63)}}
                            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (F2) {(0,7)}}   }
                        child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (E2) {(4,6)}}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D2) {(8,5)}}
                    }        
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C2) {(1,4)}}    }
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B2) {(1,3)}}
                    
                                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code fails with an error `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing `forest` can do well because, even though this isn't a tree so we need something of a hack, still the automation let's us easily produce an even, patterned spacing we can tweak as desired in the preamble of the (non-)tree.

I don't know what ['equidistantly centered'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713520/adding-additional-directed-arcs-in-a-graph-tikz-picture/713546#comment1773440_713524) means, let alone what it applies to, so this is just an example.

The code calculates the widest node and sets that width for all nodes. It places the labels more systematically than in the original (but you can change that if there's some reason for the divergence, of course). Forest tends to produce very compact trees, so we also increase the sibling separation a bit (`s sep'+=10pt`). You might also want to increase the distance between levels (e.g. `l sep+'=10pt`) or use something larger than `10pt`. If that doesn't do enough, you can modify the spacing later and more directly, if necessary.

The nodes are typeset twice: first to ascertain the widest and again to apply the dimension to all nodes. For that reason, I add the border only the second time since there's no real point typesetting it the first time.

If you really wanted the same label for the whole tree, you could obviously just set that. I'm assuming that's just for the example, however, since people rarely want to emphasise that a value is constant by repeating it over and over. For that reason, I've just used `(0,0)` as a placeholder, just as you did.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713546/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}    
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    edge+={-Latex},
    anchor=base,
    align=@{}c@{},
    font=\sffamily,
    s sep'+=10pt,
    if={ > On= On> & {n}{2} {level}{1} }{%
      edge path'={%
        (!uu2.parent anchor) edge (.child anchor)
        (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)
      },
    }{%
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)},
    },
  },
  my label/.style={%
    if n=2{%
      label={[my label style]right:{#1}},
    }{%
      label={[my label style]left:{#1}},
    },
  },
  /tikz/my label style/.style={font=\sffamily},
  before computing xy={%
    tempdima/.max={ > OOw2+d {max x}{min x}{#1-#2} }{tree},
    for tree={%
      minimum width/.register=tempdima,
      draw,
      thin,
    },
    typeset nodes,
  },
  [{(1,58)}, my label={(0,0)}
    [{(7,59)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(3,40)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(9,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
          [{(65,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(1,63)}, my label={(0,0)}]
            [{(0,7)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
          [{(4,6)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        ]
        [{(8,5)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(1,4)}, my label={(0,0)}]
    ]
    [{(1,3)}, my label={(0,0)}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Note that my pasted images suck right now due to a bug in KDE6/Okular, even though the PDF is fine. I apologise for the crappy quality. It should be clear enough to demonstrate the even spacing of the nodes. This is a basically a function of standardising their widths.

[image: scrappy quality image of evenly spaced tree]

The arrows are not really hairy, I promise; their shagginess is entirely in the eyes of Okular.

Answer (score 3):

Just add them to the suite manually as paths between nodes. here, I created a `scope` to add arrows to all paths with the `every path/.style`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\begin{document}
    
\def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\shft{-6*\lvld} % Calculate the yshift for the green tree
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
                        level 4/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=black,thick,-latex}}%,
                        %edgeup/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=green!50!black,thick,latex-}}
                        ]
        \node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (A) {(1,58)}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B1) {(7,59)}
                child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (C1) {(3,40)}
                    child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (D1) {(9,1)}
                        child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (E1) {(65,1)}
                            child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (F1) {(1,63)}}
                            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (F2) {(0,7)}}   }
                        child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (E2) {(4,6)}}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D2) {(8,5)}}
                    }        
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C2) {(1,4)}}    }
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B2) {(1,3)}};
 \begin{scope}[every path/.style={thick,-{latex}}]
  \draw (B2)--(C2);
  \draw(C2)--(D2);
    \draw (D2)--(E2);
  \draw(E2)--(F2);
\end{scope}                    
                               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### For the nodes to be all aligned vertically:

the sibling distance parameter only needs to be the same at each level : `sibling distance=2cm`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\begin{document}
    
\def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\shft{-6*\lvld} % Calculate the yshift for the green tree
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        sibling distance=2cm,
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=black,thick,-latex}}%,
                        %edgeup/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=green!50!black,thick,latex-}}
                        ]
        \node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (A) {(1,58)}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B1) {(7,59)}
                child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (C1) {(3,40)}
                    child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (D1) {(9,1)}
                        child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (E1) {(65,1)}
                            child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (F1) {(1,63)}}
                            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (F2) {(0,7)}}   }
                        child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (E2) {(4,6)}}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D2) {(8,5)}}
                    }        
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C2) {(1,4)}}    }
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B2) {(1,3)}};
 \begin{scope}[every path/.style={thick,-{latex}}]
  \draw (B2)--(C2);
  \draw(C2)--(D2);
    \draw (D2)--(E2);
  \draw(E2)--(F2);
\end{scope}                    
                               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Thank you! I just wanted a more generic way if possible so that they are all equidistantly centered.

Comment: what should be centered? the tips of the arrows?

Comment: I think having (1,4) exactly in the middle between (7,59) and (1,3), (8,5) exactly in the middle between (3,40) and (1,4), etc will be better. This may help with the position of arrows.

Comment: It is enough that each level has the same distance with the `sibling distance=2cm` parameter for example

Comment: I updated the answer by centering the nodes as you wish.