# Forest structure with redundant arc

Tags: forest

I am trying to use the forest structure offered here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713546/,
but on a different tree. I get a picture but one arc is redundant (from (0,0) to (5,5)), and I cannot figure out why. Also even a graph is produced, there is an error message: "No shape named `' known".
Can you please suggest how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713546/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}    
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    edge+={-Latex},
    anchor=base,
    align=@{}c@{},
    font=\sffamily,
    s sep'+=10pt,
    if={ > On= On> & {n}{2} {level}{1} }{%
      edge path'={%
        (!uu2.parent anchor) edge (.child anchor)
        (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)
      },
    }{%
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)},
    },
  },
  my label/.style={%
    if n=2{%
      label={[my label style]right:{#1}},
    }{%
      label={[my label style]left:{#1}},
    },
  },
  /tikz/my label style/.style={font=\sffamily},
  before computing xy={%
    tempdima/.max={ > OOw2+d {max x}{min x}{#1-#2} }{tree},
    for tree={%
      minimum width/.register=tempdima,
      draw,
      thin,
    },
    typeset nodes,
  },
  [{(0,0)}, my label={(0,0)}
    [{(1,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(2,2)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(3,3)}, my label={(0,0)}
                 [{(4,4)}, my label={(0,0)}]
            ]    
            [{(5,5)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]                   
    ]  
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one's a tree, so simpler than the previous diagram. We don't need to add extra edges and simply removing that code solves both problems. That is, we just delete

```
if={ > On= On> & {n}{2} {level}{1} }{%
  edge path'={%
    (!uu2.parent anchor) edge (.child anchor)
    (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)
  },
}{%
  edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)},
},
```

Actually, both problems are really the same. In each case, Forest tries to access a non-existent node. The arrow gets drawn from the root node just because that's the default starting point.

The reason Forest tries to access a non-existent node is because my previous answer depended on the structure of that particular tree. In particular, for lower levels of the tree, it traced paths from each second child to their grandparent's second child.

```
if={ > On= On> & {n}{2} {level}{1} }{%
```

This distinguishes between nodes for which the node is-the-second-child-and-the-level-greater-than-1 and the nodes for which one or other of those conditions fails i.e. the node isn't the second child or the node is at level 0 or 1.

Where we have is-the-second-child-and-the-level-greater-than-1,

```
  edge path'={%
    (!uu2.parent anchor) edge (.child anchor)
    (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)
  },
```

This draws two arrows. The first is drawn from the grandparent's second child's `parent anchor` to the `child anchor` of the current node. This is where the code relies on the structure of the tree. If there is no such nodes, we get an error.

```
}{%
```

Where one of the conditions fails i.e. level is 0 or 1 or the node isn't the second child,

```
  edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)},
```

This draws a single arrow from the parent's `parent anchor` to the current node's `child anchor`. This is just what Forest does by default, so I could have left this out.

```
},
```

This code doesn't work in the new tree because there is no grandparent's second child. But we don't need second arrows anyway, so we can just excise the code.

Modified code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713546/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}    
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    edge+={-Latex},
    anchor=base,
    align=@{}c@{},
    font=\sffamily,
    s sep'+=10pt,
  },
  my label/.style={%
    if n=2{%
      label={[my label style]right:{#1}},
    }{%
      label={[my label style]left:{#1}},
    },
  },
  /tikz/my label style/.style={font=\sffamily},
  before computing xy={%
    tempdima/.max={ > OOw2+d {max x}{min x}{#1-#2} }{tree},
    for tree={%
      minimum width/.register=tempdima,
      draw,
      thin,
    },
    typeset nodes,
  },
  [{(0,0)}, my label={(0,0)}
    [{(1,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(2,2)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(3,3)}, my label={(0,0)}
                 [{(4,4)}, my label={(0,0)}]
            ]    
            [{(5,5)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]                   
    ]  
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

With apologies again for the crappy quality Okular's bug produces,

[image: modified code output]