# Equal distances between nodes of a tree in each level

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have a tree but want that the distances between rectangles at each level to be equal (equal spaces between rectangles at each level). The idea for the tree was taken here: [Adding additional directed arcs in a graph (tikz picture)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713520/adding-additional-directed-arcs-in-a-graph-tikz-picture/713546#713546)
I need to adjust the distances.
Help would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\begin{document}
    
\def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance

\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm}, %level B
                        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.7cm}, %level c
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance= 1.9cm},
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=black,thick,-latex}}]
        \node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (A) {(1,1,1)}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B1) {(2,2,2)}
                child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (C1) {(5,5,5)}  
                    child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (D1) {(11,11,11)}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D2) {(12,12,12)}} }                
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C2) {(6,6,6)} 
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D3) {(13,13,13)}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D4) {(14,14,14)}
                        child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (E1) {(19,19,19)}}}}
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C3) {(7,7,7)}  
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D5) {(15,15,15)}}}}
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B2) {(3,3,3)}
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C4) {(8,8,8)}       }}
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B3) {(4,4,4)}
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C5) {(9,9,9)}   
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D6) {(16,16,16)}}}
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C6) {(10,10,10)}            
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D7) {(17,17,17)}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D8) {(18,18,18)}}}};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the distance between level n and level n+1 to be equal for all n? That is, vertical spacing should be equal? Or do you you mean that for any level n, you want all the rectangles at level n to be spaced equally? That is, equal horizontal space?

Comment: Off-topic(ish): Don't use `figure*` or `figure` with `standalone` class.

Comment: You've linked a `forest` answer, but seem to be using the other answer? Or not `forest` anyway. So it isn't clear whether you want `forest` or not. Also, I *think* you want equal horizontal spacing of nodes on a single level, but this is going to make for an ungainly and impractically wide tree unless you change other elements of the design fairly significantly. What exactly do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the desired result, but since you linked a solution using `forest`, I converted your tree to a forest.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\usepackage{forest}

\def\lvld{1.2cm}                  % Choose level distance

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
   for tree={draw=black, s sep=1cm, l sep=\lvld,
    edge={draw=black,thick,-latex}},
  [{(1,1,1)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
    [{(2,2,2)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
        [{(5,5,5)}, label=left:{(0,0)}
            [{(11,11,11)}, label=left:{(0,0)}]
            [{(12,12,12)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
        ]
        [{(6,6,6)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
            [{(13,13,13)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
            [{(14,14,14)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
                [{(19,19,19)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
            ]
            [{(7,7,7)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
                [{(15,15,15)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [{(3,3,3)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
       [{(8,8,8)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
    ]
    [{(4,4,4)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
        [{(9,9,9)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
            [{(16,16,16)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
        ]
        [{(10,10,10)}, label=right:{(0,0)}
            [{(17,17,17)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
            [{(18,18,18)}, label=right:{(0,0)}]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: conversion to forest]

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand the question, but I think you're asking to have the nodes on each level spread out equally horizontally. If that's right, I suggest it isn't what you should want and probably isn't even what you do want. The second example below makes a halfhearted attempt to implement that desideratum in order to show why you probably don't want it. Basically, unless you have a highly symmetrical tree, the result will look awful and the tree will grow impractically wide. Either that or the edges (the lines between parent nodes and their children) will occur at all kinds of odd angles. If that's really what you want, I suggest not drawing a tree at all, but using something like a `matrix of nodes` and adding the edges in afterwards.

The first example below is a somewhat streamlined version of the code jlab provided. It tries to strike a balance between symmetry and tidiness. Whether it gets that balance right is debatable, but the result looks reasonable to my eyes.

The second example, as mentioned above, goes some way towards equalising the horizontal space between nodes on the same level. It only does this for nodes with the same parent but, even so, you can see how unbalanced the tree is getting. To equalise the spacing between all nodes on the same level would require further stretching the tree and allowing the path from the root through `(3,3,3)` to `(8,8,8)`, for example, to zig-zag oddly. This is doable, but I see no value in the doing of it.

The third example uses `forked edges` from the `edges` library. This uses edges which go straight down, straight across and straight down. So mismatching angles are eliminated but the tree is still quite compact. If this is an option, you could adjust the spacing further if desired, but this style may or may not be acceptable in your discipline.

The fourth example uses a `matrix of nodes` to demonstrate how to set the nodes out in a matrix. It doesn't impose the requested equalisation of spacing. Instead it demonstrates the method you can use to adjust the spacing as desired. If you want more space in general, increase `column sep`. If you want more space between specific columns, add additional spacing to the first row as illustrated following columns 7 and 8 in the example. By naming the matrix `m`, you can then add the arrows using names of the form `(m-<row>-<column>)` as shown in the `\foreach` loop following the matrix setup. It is useful to add `nodes in empty cells` when adjusting the matrix because this gives you references for everything. Once you've got the arrows sorted, you simply delete the addition to get rid of the squares in all the empty spaces (which are just the effect of `nodes={draw}`).

Which, if any, of these trees may or may not suit your purposes I don't know.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714369/ addaswyd o ateb jlab: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713651/ a chwestiwn Vika: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713642/
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  block/.style={
    font=\sffamily,
    draw=black,
    thin,
    fill=white!50,
    outer sep=0pt,
  },
}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={my label}{},
  declare boolean={my label done}{0},
  equalise s sep/.style={%
    for tree={%
      edge+={-Latex},
      anchor=base,
      align=@{}c@{},
      font=\sffamily,
    },
  },
  equalise node widths/.style={%
    before packing={%
      tempdima/.max={ > OOw2+d {max x}{min x}{##1-##2} }{tree},
      for tree={%
        minimum width/.register=tempdima,
      },
      typeset nodes,
    },
  },
  calign central child or midpoint/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where={ > Ow+P {n children}{isodd(##1)} }
      {%
        calign primary child/.process={ Ow+P {n children}{int((##1+1)/2)}},
        calign=child edge,
      }{%
        calign=edge midpoint,
      },
    },
  },
  my labels/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for nodewalk={%
        root,
        label/.process={ Ow{my label}{[my label style]left:{##1}}},
        last leaf,
        label/.process={ Ow{my label}{[my label style]below:{##1}}},
        fit=band,
        while nodewalk valid={previous leaf}{%
          previous leaf,
          label/.process={ Ow{my label}{[my label style]below:{##1}}},
        },
        while nodewalk valid={parent}{%
          parent,
          label/.process={ Ow{my label}{[my label style]left:{##1}}},
        },
      }{my label done},
      where my label done={}{%
        label/.process={ Ow{my label}{[my label style]right:{##1}}},
      },
    },
  },
  equalise s sep by level/.style={%
    before computing xy={%
      for tree children-first={%
        if={ > On> {n children}{1} }{%l[1] l[2]
          tempdima={ > Ow+d  O  > ? p {!first.s}{-##1} {!last.s} {Ow+d{!first.s}{-##1}} {O{!last.s}} },
          !first.s=-\foresteregister{tempdima},
          !last.s/.register=tempdima,
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
  /tikz/my label style/.style={font=\sffamily},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    block,
    s sep'=30pt, 
    l sep'=20pt,
    edge+={draw=black,thick,-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  equalise node widths,
  calign central child or midpoint,
  my labels,
  [{(1,1,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
    [{(2,2,2)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(5,5,5)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(11,11,11)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        [{(12,12,12)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(6,6,6)}, my label={(0,0)}
          [{(13,13,13)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          [{(14,14,14)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(19,19,19)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
          [{(7,7,7)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(15,15,15)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
      ]
    ]
    [{(3,3,3)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(8,8,8)}, my label={(0,0)},fit=band]
    ]
    [{(4,4,4)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(9,9,9)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(16,16,16)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(10,10,10)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(17,17,17)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        [{(18,18,18)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    block,
    s sep'=30pt, 
    l sep'=20pt,
    edge+={draw=black,thick,-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  equalise node widths,
  calign central child or midpoint,
  equalise s sep by level, 
  my labels,
  [{(1,1,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
    [{(2,2,2)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(5,5,5)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(11,11,11)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        [{(12,12,12)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(6,6,6)}, my label={(0,0)}
          [{(13,13,13)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          [{(14,14,14)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(19,19,19)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
          [{(7,7,7)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(15,15,15)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
      ]
    ]
    [{(3,3,3)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(8,8,8)}, my label={(0,0)},fit=band]
    ]
    [{(4,4,4)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(9,9,9)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(16,16,16)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(10,10,10)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(17,17,17)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        [{(18,18,18)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    block,
    s sep'=30pt, 
    l sep'=20pt,
    edge+={draw=black,thick,-Latex},
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  equalise node widths,
  calign central child or midpoint,
  my labels,
  forked edges,
  [{(1,1,1)}, my label={(0,0)}
    [{(2,2,2)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(5,5,5)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(11,11,11)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        [{(12,12,12)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(6,6,6)}, my label={(0,0)}
          [{(13,13,13)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          [{(14,14,14)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(19,19,19)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
          [{(7,7,7)}, my label={(0,0)}
            [{(15,15,15)}, my label={(0,0)}]
          ]
      ]
    ]
    [{(3,3,3)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(8,8,8)}, my label={(0,0)},fit=band]
    ]
    [{(4,4,4)}, my label={(0,0)}
      [{(9,9,9)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(16,16,16)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
      [{(10,10,10)}, my label={(0,0)}
        [{(17,17,17)}, my label={(0,0)}]
        [{(18,18,18)}, my label={(0,0)}]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (m) [%
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={draw,font=\sffamily},
  row sep=10mm,
  column sep=5mm,]
  {
    & & & & && |[label=left:{(0,0)}]| (1,1,1) &[10mm] &[10mm] &  & \\
    & & & |[label=left:{(0,0)}]| (2,2,2) & && |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (3,3,3) & & & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (4,4,4) & \\
    & |[label=left:{(0,0)}]| (5,5,5) & & & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (6,6,6) && |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (8,8,8) & & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (9,9,9) & & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (10,10,10) \\
    |[label=left:{(0,0)}]| (11,11,11)  & & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (12,12,12) & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (13,13,13) & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (14,14,14) & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (7,7,7) && & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (16,16,16) & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (17,17,17) && |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (18,18,18) \\
    & & & & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (19,19,19) & |[label=right:{(0,0)}]| (15,15,15) && & & & & \\
  };
  \begin{scope}[every path/.style={draw,-Latex}]
    \foreach \i/\j in {1-7/2-7,2-7/3-7,1-7/2-4,1-7/2-10,2-4/3-2,3-2/4-1,3-2/4-3,2-4/3-5,3-5/4-4,3-5/4-5,3-5/4-6,4-5/5-5,4-6/5-6,2-10/3-9,2-10/3-11,3-11/4-12,3-11/4-10,3-9/4-9} \path (m-\i) -- (m-\j);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[Obviously needs images but that will have to wait due to an Okular bug.]